# Unable to access the Minikube ip from the host(windows) machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have created a Linux VM in VMware Workstation and installed minikube and started the minikube cluster everything is done but when I try accessing the minikube dashboard using the minikube IP from the browser of the host(windows) machine I'm unable to access it.

There are 2 different IPs. One is the VM IP which is accessible and another one is the minikube IP which is not accessible please help me how/what to configure in the VM so the minikube IP will be accessible from the host(windows) machine.

And I can access the minikube dashboard/pod-services.

Comment: You won't be able to access the minikube IP from your host machine since the minikube container's IP address would be accessible through DockerDesktopVM/Localhost  but not from your host machine(windows). You need to use minikube kubectl proxy command to work as a work around. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68845544/19230181) by moonkotte .

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: Not yet... The proxy doesn't work... I am still searching for a concrete solutions for this issue.